# Is there how to optimize a query with 2 inner join into same table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have that problem:
I have a model with those 3 tables:
Linha, Itinerario and Rua
Into Itinerario i have the reference id to Linha table and one reference with id for Rua.
In my code i recieve two arguments about idRua and i must return all Linhas where i have Itinerario the references for Rua with both idRua... In this examples where i have idRua = 1 and idRua = 2.

```
SELECT l.codigo, l.linha, l.idEmpresa, l.idLinha 
FROM Linha l 
INNER JOIN Itinerario i1 ON i1.idLinha = l.idLinha 
INNER JOIN Itinerario i2 ON i2.idLinha = l.idLinha 
WHERE i1.ida = i2.ida and i1.idRua = 1 and i2.idRua = 2 
ORDER BY l.linha
```

The problem is that i get 2 inner join in that table Itinerario and the query gets to slow...
Is there somehow to optimize it?
Is there some "IN" operator with "AND" condition or something like this?
Im using SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a way to eliminate the self-join.

If I'm reading this correctly, you want idLinha's from Itinerario that contain both idRua = 1 and idRua = 2 for the same ida.  I'm noticing that this is just a filter condition, since everything in the select comes from linha.

The following gets this condition:

```
SELECT idlinha
From itinerario
GROUP BY idlinha, ida
having max(case when idRua = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when idRua = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Now, we can use this in an "in" or "join" clause, as in:

```
SELECT l.codigo, l.linha, l.idEmpresa, l.idLinha 
FROM Linha l
where l.idlinha in (SELECT idlinha
                    From itinerario
                    GROUP BY idlinha
                    having max(case when idRua = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
                           max(case when idRua = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                   )
order by l.linha
```

It is possible that the group by will be faster than a self-join.

Comment: I did it... and my query time went from 20 seconds... for 2 seconds only... do you know the reason for that 2 selects work better then self-join?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is expressed as efficiently as it gets. You need to make sure that you have correct indexes in order for SQLite to execute the query efficiently. Make sure that an index exists on the `Itinerario` table's `idLinha` column:

```
create index Itinerario_Linha_Idx on Itinerario(idLinha)
```

An index on `idRua` may also come in handy:

```
create index Itinerario_Rua_Idx on Itinerario(idRua)
```

Comment: Hmm... I not so good with database skills... so maybe thats the reason i've dont know that stuff so much... When you say to check if index exists, i means that i must create the index, right? but if i create the table id as primary key integer... its not already used as index for performance?

Comment: @Igor When I said "make sure that an index exists" I meant that you should create one unless you already did create one. It is true that in index is created on columns declared as primary keys; however, neither `idLinha` nor `idRua` is a primary key, so adding an index on them should help.

Comment: @Igor This is very strange. How much data do you have in these tables?

Comment: @Igor How many different `ida` values do you have in `Itinerario`, compared to the total number of rows in the table?

Comment: I've used another solution posted here in this question and i got 2 seconds for the response... take a look there... really thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Because your `WHERE` conditions don't apply to table `Linha`, you could improve performance by moving the conditions into the relevant `ON` clause, where they can be applied as the inner join is being made, rather than on the result set:

```
SELECT l.codigo, l.linha, l.idEmpresa, l.idLinha 
FROM Linha l 
INNER JOIN Itinerario i1 ON i1.idLinha = l.idLinha and i1.idRua = 1
INNER JOIN Itinerario i2 ON i2.idLinha = l.idLinha and i2.idRua = 2 and i1.ida = i2.ida
ORDER BY l.linha
```

Also, you must have an index on `Itinerario(idLinha)`. An index on `Itinerario(idRua)` almost certainly won't help.

For best performance with the above query, create an index on *both* `idLinha` and `idRua`:

```
create index Itinerario_Index1 on Itinerario(idLinha, idRua);
```

With both `idLinha` and `idRua` in the `ON` clause, both parts of the index can be used, so the database will only read in the exact row(s) it needs, minimizing I/O.

Comment: I've tryed that... it wents better then before.. but im still getting to slow.. 20 seconds... for 28848 data into Itinerario Table... running into android

Comment: Thanks for helping!! I've used solution made by Gordon. I got the response in 2 seconds... Really thanks!!